# DataGridView and GenericDataGridView

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, datagridview

Is there a control called GenericDataGridView and how do I add that to Visual Studio 2008 so I can use it in my c# application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yes, there is](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/GenericDataGridView.aspx).

You can download the [source files](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/GenericDataGridView/GenericDataGridView_src.zip) and compile the project.
Then, right-click the toolbox, click Choose Items, browse to the compiled DLL, and add it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. Is there any harm of doing this, will I face any compatibility issues later if I run my app in another vs2008? What would you recommend? Customize and use the normal DataGridView or better to use this one? I only need to have textboxes and few dropdowns in my gird. thanks

Comment: @Zerone: This will have no effect at all on any project that doesn't reference the DLL.

Comment: To open the project on another computer, you will need to make sure that the other computer has the DLL somewhere.  (You can bundle the grid's DLL along with your project)

Answer (score 1):

here is the link for the grid view control which is for linq ans also for sql queries

LINQ TO SQL GridView (Enhanced Gridview) : - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/LINQ_TO_SQL_GridView.aspx

ASP.NET Extended Grid Control : -
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/EnhanceGrid.aspx